# Display saved time in UIDatePicker after re-run app

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, uidatepicker

I can set the time for notifications by UIDatePicker. But if I close the app and run again, then time will be reset to the current one. Although the notifications themselves will appear in the previously prescribed time. How can I make displayed time in UIDatePicker (timeDatePicker and timeDatePickerSecond) which I saved earlier (after click Schedule)?

[image]

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

class Notifications: UIViewController, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var scheludeMeal: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var timeDatePicker: UIDatePicker!
    @IBOutlet weak var timeDatePickerSecond: UIDatePicker!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
            if granted {
                print("Yes!")
            } else {
                print("No...?")
            }
        }

    }


    @IBAction func scheludeButton(_ sender: Any) {

        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

        center.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()

        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Notification!"
        content.body = "Description of notification :)"
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

        let dateComponent = timeDatePicker.calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: timeDatePicker.date)
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponent, repeats: true)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
        center.add(request)

        let dateComponentSd = timeDatePickerSecond.calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: timeDatePickerSecond.date)
        let trigger2 = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponentSd, repeats: true)
        let request2 = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger2)
        center.add(request2)

    }

}
```

Comment: Try this datePicker.setDate(yourDate, animated: false)

Comment: @Sateesh thanks! this way `timeDatePicker.setDate(dateComponent, animated: false)` for scheludeButton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UserDefaults` to persist the `Date` object between app launches. You just need to make sure that you save the newly selected `Date` object in `scheduleButton` and that you load the value from `UserDefaults` in `viewDidLoad` to set as the default date on your picker.

You can find the described solution implemented for `timeDatePicker`, but if you also need it for `timeDatePickerSecond`, just create another `Date?` property for that and implement it likewise, but make sure you use a different `UserDefaults` key for that second property.

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

class Notifications: UIViewController, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var scheludeMeal: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var timeDatePicker: UIDatePicker!
    @IBOutlet weak var timeDatePickerSecond: UIDatePicker!

    var savedNotificationDate: Date? {
        get {
            return UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "notificationDate") as? Date
        }
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "notificationDate")
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let savedNotificationDate = savedNotificationDate {
            timeDatePicker.date = savedNotificationDate
        }

        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
            if granted {
                print("Yes!")
            } else {
                print("No...?")
            }
        }

    }


    @IBAction func scheludeButton(_ sender: Any) {

        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

        center.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()

        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Notification!"
        content.body = "Description of notification :)"
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

        let dateComponent = timeDatePicker.calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: timeDatePicker.date)
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponent, repeats: true)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
        center.add(request)
        savedNotificationDate = timeDatePicker.date

        let dateComponentSd = timeDatePickerSecond.calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: timeDatePickerSecond.date)
        let trigger2 = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponentSd, repeats: true)
        let request2 = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger2)
        center.add(request2)

    }

}
```